# Whitelist per contact for sender addresses I may use

Tags: contact-manager, thunderbird

I have a private and a business email address (in the same Thunderbird profile). When sending an email to someone I know in both worlds (who also has a private and a business email address), it can easily happen to send from or send to the wrong address.

I would like to have a Thunderbird add-on that allows me to specify¹ a whitelist² per contact which lists the sending address(es) I may use.

If trying to send from a non-whitelisted address, it should warn me (instead of correcting it automatically).

It should not require me to specify a whitelist for all contacts.

---

¹ I want to specify the whitelists manually. Example: for my contact alice@example.com, I add "unor@example.org" to the whitelist. Now when I try to send an email to alice@example.com, I can only do so if I select unor@example.org as sender address.

² While a blacklist would work in the case of only two accounts, too, I actually have many more accounts, so it should be a whitelist.